# If не работает?

Tags: c#, unity3d

```
       Debug.Log("level is null " + l is null);

        if (l is null)
        {
            Debug.Log("set new level ");
            Debug.Log("set new level " + l is null);
}
```

Этот код выводит
False
set new level
False
Что тут не так? Блок if не должен же срабатывать.
Unity3d

Comment: я полагаю -  порядок выполнения операторов

Comment: а можно поподробнее?

Comment: попробуйте взять в скобки `(l is null)` или вынести это выражение в переменную

Comment: Не могу воспроизвести вашу проблему. Что такое `l`? Какого оно типа?

Comment: `Debug.Log("level is null " + (l is null));`

Comment: А вообще, конечно, не делайте так никогда, используйте форматирование для вывода, а не конкатенацию строк и переменных.

Comment: Всем спасибо, действительно конкатенация строк ввела меня в заблуждение. Еще один плюс к опыту.